# Chrome-frame 25.0.1364.97 rendering

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, rendering, google-chrome-frame

We have intranet web- system, and most of our employees use IE with chrome frame installed on it. So, all worked fine while chrome-frame had updated to version 25.0.1364.97.
Now, with this new version, there is rendering problem - seems that page renders not to end - some html blocks goes out of there parents and etc. When refreshing page - all is fine.
Page works good on all browsers, including IE. But we want to use chrome-frame, because it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

We have encountered similar issue with this release of Chrome Frame with javascript being written to the header of the page.  I have tried dropping an issue report on the Google Release site, but the website seems to be down.  We have confirmed that this issue doesn't exist in previous releases of Chrome Frame.